# Google sheets - Group by and Order by query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=QUERY(A5:L100, "select B,C,max(K) where K>'0' Group by B,C Order by max(K) desc Limit 15 label B 'Final Governor ID', C 'Final Governor Name', max(K) 'Final Bid'",-1)
```

The data is being ordered by column B, the only reason I can think of is that Column B is also a number but it's an ID.
I'm not too experienced, more self taught but can't seem to find anything online to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

The problem starts with your formula in cell `K2`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(J5:J100="Yes",H5:H100,"0"))
```

You use double quotations aound your 0. This results in giving `0`s as text instead of numbers. You can check that by using the formula `=ISNUMBER(K5)` and so on for the rest of your cells.

To remedy this you need to use

=ArrayFormula(IF(J5:J100="Yes",H5:H100,0))

Notice **no double quotation**

After that, proceed by also removing the single quotation as suggested in the original answer.

**Original answer.**

Try removing the single quotes around `0` which is a number.

```
=QUERY(A5:L100, "select B,C,max(K) where K>0 Group by B,C Order by max(K) desc Limit 15 label B 'Final Governor ID', C 'Final Governor Name', max(K) 'Final Bid'",-1)
```

Comment: that returned no values.

Comment: Please share some more [data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets/info)

Comment: I added a link above

Comment: I would suggest you TAKE DOWN THE LINK IMMEDIATELY. NEVER SHARE ORIGINAL files. Create a small sample sheet you can share.. Please do read [ask] and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311)

Comment: It's a copy, genuinely nothing important or private on there

Comment: Even so. The data there is huge. Too many rows, too many columns and 12 sheets !!!! And not even a mention on the tab you refer to. Sorry. Please try again.

Comment: well the link text said tab name and cell. But it's fine I'll just go back to trying to do my own research

Comment: your way broke the other formula for ranks so I just made it to =ArrayFormula(IF(J5:J100="Yes",H5:H100,""))  and it seem to do the trick.
I wanted to share the whole sheet because I knew it was a hot mess of evolution.
Thanks though